# close/leave page event with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies, single-page-application, dom-events

I am trying to implement a single page application that starts with a login form. For front-end I'm using AngularJS.

In the login's controller I check the authentication data, and if it is ok, I set a cookie (using $cookieStore service) with some user data and route to another view. Here, in the controller of the second view I check if the user from the cookie is empty and if yes, I redirect to the login view.

What I want to do is when the user close the browser, or if leaves the page the cookie to be removed.
I have tried to use:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(){
    $cookieStore.remove('user');
});
```

or

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    $cookieStore.remove('user');
});
```

but it does not work. 
I want to avoid the scenario when a user log in (the cookie is set) and is redirected successfully to the second view, and after this close the browser/leaves the page (the cookie is still there). Another user write the url of the second view and because the cookie with the data of the first user is still there, he succeed to authenticate.

Can anyone help me with this?

[plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/x7yUD9pow5WQBURhcnGb)

Comment: cookie session expire would be better... very hard to manage event of user closing browser.... power fail is prime example

Comment: in AngularJS for service $cookieStore it cannot be set an expire time: [link](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore)

Comment: @user2831737 hi, Im in the same situation. Did you find any good solution? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But maybe the browser closes before you even do anything in your logic.

Try this :

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    $cookieStore.remove('user');
});
```

Comment: It is not working like this... I have added a Plunker where I illustrate what I am trying to do. Use "launch in a separate window". Add the username: aaa, psw: bbb, and login. Copy the url and go to another site, then paste the url and you will be logged in again, without going to login view. The event $locationChangeStart is not caught when going to another site.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it will works

```
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event) {
    if($scope.formsubmitted && $scope.myForm.$dirty){   
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
            if (!answer) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
          $cookieStore.remove('user');
        }
    }
 });
```